# Activity in popup window outside of my application

Tags: android

I have an activity and layout that I want to be able to start on top of whatever application is currently open on the phone or the home screen, but i want the activity to start in a semi transparent pop-like window that the user can interact with. I'm not sure where to start, any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting your activity from a service, you can do something like this:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),DialogActivity.class);
                    // If invoking from outside app activity, needs to include 
                    // New task flag.
                    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Your activity can have a dialog theme so that it is shown as a dialog.

Comment: Thank you, I will be starting my activity from a service so it looks like this should work!

Comment: How would you implement the new task flag?

Comment: This takes care of new task flag: dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: I tried your code but I'm having some issues, maybe you could take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980070/launching-a-dialog-box-without-main-application-bellow